# How to SELECT users who worked every month within a period?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

How would you modify this query to return to me, all the users IDs who have worked in all 12 months of the year?

```
SELECT extract(month from Date_worked) as Month,user_id FROM Users WHERE
 Date_worked >= '01/JAN/16' and Date_worked < '01/JAN/17'
```

This currently returns me something like this:

```
MONTH - USER_ID
1        12
2        12
3        11
3        12
4        11
4        12
5        12
6        12
7        12
8        12
9        12
10       12
11       12
12       12   
...
```

In this case, the query should only return USER_ID 12 because it's associated with all 12 months.

Comment: alter your question to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    user_id
FROM Users
WHERE Date_worked >= '01/JAN/16' AND Date_worked < '01/JAN/17'
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 12
```

If a user could have more than one record associated with a given month, then count distinct months using the following `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(month from Date_worked)) = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT extract(month from Date_worked) as Month,user_id
FROM Users GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT extract(month from Date_worked) ) = 12
```

Try above query.

Comment: I am getting the following error with this query:"not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: @Shayme27 which one?